# condition in linqToXml

Tags: xml, linq, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

XML

```
<Questions>
   <Question>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Text>aaa</Text>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Text>bbb</Text>
   </Question>
</Questions>
```

Code

```
question="aaa";

var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Questions.xml");
        var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("Question")
                       let txt = element.Element("Text")
                       where question.CompareTo (txt)==0 
                       select new
                       {
                           Id = element.Element("Id").Value,
                       };
```

This code elements.count()==>0

I would Like that select from xml where `txt=='aaa'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `let txt = element.Element("Text")` returns a XElement instead of the text so your `CompareTo` condition will blow up instead of checking the text values.

Instead you can get the value of the node via the `.Value` property.

```
...
let txt = element.Element("Text").Value
...
```

The line `var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("Question")` will successfully lookup the elements but as a practice you might want to go from the root node or relative hierarchy.

```
...
var elements = from element in doc.Root.Descendants("Question")
...
```

The rest of the code seems fine (less exception handling).

The following worked for me...

```
string xml = @"<Questions>
   <Question>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Text>aaa</Text>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Text>bbb</Text>
   </Question>
</Questions>";

string question = @"aaa";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elements = from element in doc.Root.Descendants("Question")
           let txt = element.Element("Text").Value
           where question.CompareTo(txt)==0 
           select new
           {
               Id = element.Element("Id").Value,
           };

Console.WriteLine(elements.Count()); //1
```